# Pytesseract (OCR) not recognizing this (easily apparent) image

Tags: python, ocr

Why isn't pytesseract identifying [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o47L.jpg)?

```
import pyautogui, pytesseract
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('test.png')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im))
```

Oddly enough, the same image works if the text is +1.5 or something above 1, but it doesn't work on any negative number or on anything between 0 and 1. I know there are a few parameters you can use to increase pytesseract's accuracy, but I don't know which ones would be applicable here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case you could turn the image into black and white before applying OCR.

```
im = im.convert('1', dither=Image.NONE)
```

Using this, you can get the correct result: `-7.6`

Hope that helps you :)

Comment: You are awesome